# can we push read only files in git?

Tags: git, jestjs

I have few read only .js files(working on a jest debugging scenario). However, I am able to edit them using vi mode in linux. I have made the changes to the files and able to commit them in to git master branch. when I try to push the changes then I am stuck with an error.

**Error: trying to modify a read only file.**

Steps followed:

1. Edited a read only file using vi and saved using :wq!
2. git add file name
3. git commit
4. git push origin master .... tried even 'git push origin master:new_branch'

At this command I am facing the error stated above.

How can I push a read only file ?

Comment: In your case : where is your `origin` repo hosted ? is it a local repo ? a repo hosted on github ? gitlab ? a self hosted solution ? ...

Comment: Can you run `git push origin master` from a terminal, and copy/paste the output of that command ? (you can edit the elements that would identify too clearly a user or your company if you want ...)

Comment: Technically, you don't ever push *files*.  You push *commits*. See LeGEC's answer for a more useful point though.

Comment: I have tried git push origin master and got the same error. Actually, this was performed in online IDE during a debugging issue. I don't have the setup with me.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is not about files you try to push, it is about files that `git` tries to modify.

`git push` may trigger two kinds of "write" operations :

1. in some circumstances, it will try to create a so-called packed file in your local `.git/` folder,
2. it will have to update some files on the remote repository.

Depending on the error message : you should inspect the access rights on your local `.git/` folder, or the access rights on the git repo in the remote server.